# Task permisssions denied with Full Control

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have a user that has Full Control permissions on the entire site. When a workflow is assigned to them, they randomly recieve the following incorrect email message indicating they do not have permission on the task library, when in fact they do. They can view their tasks in the Tasks library without any problems.

> You do not have the required
>   permissions to view this task.
>
> To complete this task:
>
> 1. Request access.
> 2. Review your task for specific details about this request.
> 3. Perform the specific activities required for this task.
> 4. Use the Edit this task button to mark the task as completed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if they have multiple user profiles or accounts.  When using workflow in some instanced those tasks can only be completed by the user assigned the task so it may not be identifying them as the person with the task assigned

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mike. Could you please elaborate where I should be looking for multiple accounts? When I use the "Add Recipents" dialog, I only get one entry for the user.